# How to change getDisplayMedia information url to custom name?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I want to change "[url] wants to share the contents of your screen" to "MyCustomName wants to share the contents of your screen" with getDisplayMedia dialog

[image: getDisplayMedia example]

Comment: There's no way. You can suggest implementing it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: which will likely be rejected. The extension name is listed there as a security measure, as it is done for the getDisplayMedia API which lists the web page origin requesting to share.

Comment: What about if chrome extension requesting so? Contents can be injected on any page and some random page requesting screen share on behalf of chrome extension seems not logical @PhilippHancke